# Not able to add element in an empty array. Difference between insert,append and concatenate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

Que: Given a matrix mat of size 3 x 3. Find all the even numbers situated in each of the row(s) whose end cumulative sum is greater than or equal to 150.

```
[[ 51  21  14]
 [ 56  85  22]
 [ 99 666 230]]
```

Answer: [ 56  22 666 230]

```
import numpy as np 

mat = np.array([[51,21,14], 
                [56,85,22], 
                [99,666,230]]).reshape(3,3)



mat = np.array([[51,21,14],[56,85,22],[99,666,230]]).reshape(3,3)
dim = np.arange(0,mat.ndim+1)
a = np.array([])

for ele in mat:
    if np.sum(ele)>=150:
        for c in ele:
            if c%2==0:
                np.insert(a,0,[c])
                print(a)
```

Issue: I am getting empty array. Now I tried append,concatenate as well. I believe there is something fundamentally wrong in code when inserting element.
Can someone help as well as share a link/concept explaining the differnce between insert,concatenate and append focussed specially for numpy arrays.

TIA.

Comment: `insert` is a function that returns a new array.  It does not operate in-place.  Same for `np.append` and `concatenate`.  To use these correctly you need a good understanding of array `shape`.  And read their docs.  If you are going to work iteratively, use lists, and don't try to force arrays into the list model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iteration isn't the best way to approach this problem.  All of these operations are easily `vectorize`able with `numpy`:

```
m = mat.sum(1) >= 150
t = mat[m]
t[t % 2 == 0]
```

```
array([ 56,  22, 666, 230])
```

---

***Explanation***

Create a mask of rows with a sum over 150

```
>>> m = mat.sum(1) >= 150
>>> m
array([False,  True,  True])
```

Index your array with the boolean mask

```
>>> t = mat[m]
>>> t
array([[ 56,  85,  22],
       [ 99, 666, 230]])
```

Finally, find the even elements

```
>>> t[t % 2 == 0]
array([ 56,  22, 666, 230])
```

Comment: sum(1) here is axis =1?

Comment: Ok ok yeah yours is def better. i am noob so. Thank you for simplifying.

Comment: Using `numpy` definitely takes a different mindset when you have to think about vectorized operations, but you had all the building blocks there! Happy programming!